# Why is the dependency injection of EV only partially working in my net6 console app?

Tags: dependency-injection, environment-variables, .net-6.0

### Problem description

Hi,

I got a .Net 6 console app. I use dependency injection.
I fetch the environment variables set up in the `launchsettings.json` file. This is the process for debug. In production, the app is containerized and the EV are passed through the `docker-compose.yml`

I've been using this process for a while but lately, I added more variables and only the last added EV are well fetched in the `IOption` object that is initialized by DI engine.
I don't understand why only a few EV are correctly fetched (the newly added ones) and the others are not but it was working fine until now and I didn't change the code related to this feature.

### Already tried

- Check the `launchsettings.json` format
- Fall back to the previous version of the file without the additional EV.
- Inversing the EV in the `launchsettings.json` file

### Files

#### Program.cs

```cs
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
            => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                    {
                        //var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
                        //config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                        //.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                        //.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                    })
                    .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                    {
                        logging.ClearProviders();
                        logging.AddLog4Net("log4net.config", true);
                    })
                    .ConfigureServices((hostingContext, services) =>
                    {
                        services.AddScoped<IRequestManager, RequestManager>();
                        services.AddScoped<ITimeFrameManager, TimeFrameManager>();
                        services.AddScoped<IlaService, IlaService>();
                        services.AddScoped<IDatabaseService, DatabaseService>();
                        services.AddScoped<IDiscordService, DiscordService>();
                        services.AddScoped<INotificationManager, NotificationManager>();
                        services.AddOptions<DiscordOptions>().BindConfiguration("Discord");
                        services.AddOptions<AccountOptions>().BindConfiguration("Account");                        
                    })
                    .UseConsoleLifetime();
```

#### launchsettings.json

```json
{
  "profiles": {
    "InstagramLikesApp": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "Account__Password": "xxx",
        "Account__Name": "xxxx",
        "Account__Target": "xxxx",
        "Account__NextId": "",
        "Account__NbPagesToLoad": "1",
        "Account__TwoFASecretKey": "xxx",
        "Discord__Token": "xxxx",
        "Discord__ChannelId": "xxxx"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### IOptions consuming Service

Here it doesn't work

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

        private readonly IOptions<AccountOptions> _options;

        public IlaService(IOptions<AccountOptions> options)
        {
            _options = options;
        }
```

Here it works

```cs
        private DiscordSocketClient _client;
        private ulong _channelId;

        public DiscordService(IOptions<DiscordOptions> options)
        {
            _channelId = UInt64.Parse(options.Value.ChannelId);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I found the source of the problem.
It was indeed I duplicate file. My AccountOptions file had a duplicate in another project. I deleted the duplicate file and it's working again.